# .net core API controller action with many parameters

Tags: api, controller, .net-core

I have an api action that requires 30 parameters.The problem is when i add this action in the controller class i face OverflowException.

```
[Route("api/getutilityservicebillcollection/{usba}/{usbt}/{usbpm}/{serviceUserID}" +
           "/{servicePassword}/{transactionSourceName}/{transactionSourceId}/{requestDateTime}" +
           "/{requestId}/{billNumber}/{billAccountNumber}/{billMobileNumber}/{billMonth}/{billYear}" +
           "/{billZone}/{billCategory}/{billStudentId}/{CustomerId}/{TransactionSerialNo}" +
           "/{BillToMonth}/{BillToYear}/{FromBillMonth}/{FromBillYear}/{studentBillPaymentType}" +
           "/{billPaymentAmount}/{paymentBranchId}/{paymentAccountNumber}/{exchangeCode}"+
           "/{lastPaymentDate}/{branchCode}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetUtilityServiceBillCollection(string usba,
        string usbt, string usbpm, string serviceUserID,
        string servicePassword, string transactionSourceName, string transactionSourceId, string requestDateTime,
        string requestId, string billNumber, string billAccountNumber, string billMobileNumber, string billMonth,
        string billYear, string billZone, string billCategory, string billStudentId, string CustomerId,
        string TransactionSerialNo, string BillToMonth, string BillToYear, string FromBillMonth,
        string FromBillYear, string studentBillPaymentType, string billPaymentAmount, string paymentBranchId,
        string paymentAccountNumber, string exchangeCode, string lastPaymentDate, string branchCode)
    {
        UtilityServiceBillResponse s = await Iutility.UtilityServiceBillCollection(usba,usbt,usbpm,serviceUserID,
            servicePassword,transactionSourceName,transactionSourceId,requestDateTime,requestId,billNumber,
            billAccountNumber,billMobileNumber,billMonth,billYear,billZone,billCategory,billStudentId,CustomerId,
            TransactionSerialNo,BillToMonth,BillToYear,FromBillMonth,FromBillYear, studentBillPaymentType,
            billPaymentAmount, paymentBranchId, paymentAccountNumber, exchangeCode, lastPaymentDate,
            branchCode);

        if (s == null) return NotFound();
        else return Ok(s);

    }
```

What is the problem here?

Also how am i to test this action?Is typing all the parameters at url the only option?

Comment: Can't you create a class with those properties in it? You should add the HttpsPost attribute on top of your class.

Comment: I will have to inject the parameters at url in both cases.I tried the HttpGet attribute.But doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How do you make the call to the API? Could be you have to add FromBody in your parameters.

Comment: I would make this a HttpPost with the route being [Route("api/getutilityservicebillcollection")] Then add put all those params into a dto as suggested above: public async Task<ActionResult> GetUtilityServiceBillCollection([FromBody] getBillCollectionDto dto) you will also need to pass the dto in the PostAsync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of declaring an API like that, make use of attributes to ensure that the routing for the API is done correctly.
Let's add a new attribute to explicitly define it as a POST request

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UtilityServiceBills([FromBody]UtilityServiceBillFilterViewModel vm)
        {
            // Do something to vm

            return Ok();
        }
```

And here's the ViewModel

```
public class UtilityServiceBillFilterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Usbt { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public long BillNumber { get; set; }

        public string transactionSourceName { get; set; }

    }
```

Make sure you send the payload in like that:

```
{
  "usbt": "asdasd",
  "transactionSourceName": "asdasdasdasd",
  "billNumber": 123123123
}
```

.NET Core is smart enough to convert the JSON object over to the class stated. If you do want to know more about the difference between a [FromBody] based POST API and a non-[FromBody] based one, [check this out](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/)